# While assigning a PHP array to a JS array, each alphabet of the values of the array gets split

Tags: javascript, php

This is the code:

```
<?php
$array = array('RANAJI', 'YAARA MAULA', 'AARAMBH', 'AISI SAZAA', 'SHEHER', 'BEEDO', 'DUNIYA', 'RAAT KE MUSAFIR');
foreach ($array as $item) echo $item.'<br>';
?>

<script>
var i;
var name = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
for(i=0;i<name.length;i++){
document.write(name[i]+'<br>');
}
</script>
```

And this is the output:

> RANAJI
>
> YAARA MAULA
>
> AARAMBH
>
> AISI SAZAA
>
> SHEHER
>
> BEEDO
>
> DUNIYA
>
> RAAT KE MUSAFIR
>
> R
>
> A
>
> N
>
> A
>
> J
>
> I
>
> ,
>
> Y
>
> A
>
> A
>
> R
>
> A
>
> M
>
> A
>
> U
>
> L
>
> A
>
> ,
>
> A
>
> A
>
> A
>
> M
>
> B
>
> H
>
> ,
>
> A
>
> I
>
> S
>
> I
>
> S
>
> A
>
> Z
>
> A
>
> A
>
> ,
>
> S
>
> H
>
> E
>
> H
>
> E
>
> R
>
> ,
>
> B
>
> E
>
> E
>
> D
>
> O
>
> ,
>
> D
>
> U
>
> N
>
> I
>
> Y
>
> A
>
> ,
>
> R
>
> A
>
> A
>
> T
>
> K
>
> E
>
> M
>
> U
>
> S
>
> A
>
> F
>
> I
>
> R

So, how to store the values in the same way as they are stored in the PHP array?

Comment: Then what is your question ?

Comment: How to store the values in the same way as they are stored in the PHP array?

Comment: What is the result of the output HTML from the PHP file? It seems to treat it like a concatenated string in the Javascript for-loop.

Comment: @kb. The output in the question is what that HTML page is giving.

Comment: @VermaJr. I am talking about the actual HTML source that is returned by the server, it will not contain the ````<?php```` but rather the result of the echo. (But nevermind :), seems like it was a scope issue.)

Comment: yes, the problem is solved :)

Comment: `const name = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;` will also get you your desired result. ES6, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable 'name' is the problem, change it to something like 'foo' and it should work

```
<?php
$array = array('RANAJI', 'YAARA MAULA', 'AARAMBH', 'AISI SAZAA', 'SHEHER', 'BEEDO', 'DUNIYA', 'RAAT KE MUSAFIR');
foreach ($array as $item) echo $item.'<br>';
?>

<script>
var i;
var foo = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
for(i=0;i<foo.length;i++){
document.write(foo[i]+'<br>');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are executing this in global scope. There is already a [`name` property on the global window object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name). This among other reasons is why people will tell you not to declare variables in the global scope.

What is happening is your array is getting coereced into a string value in order to save it into the `window.name` property and hence why doing `name[i]` retrieves a letter instead of a word.

Name your variable something else

```
var i;
var nameArr = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
for(i=0;i<nameArr.length;i++){
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',nameArr[i]+'<br>');
}
```

Also try not to use `document.write` there are other DOM methods/properties that you can use to insert html/text