# const vs var and the window.name property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Just came across the following in a recent [question I was looking at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37553894/while-assigning-a-php-array-to-a-js-array-each-alphabet-of-the-values-of-the-ar), and I'm curious as to why `var name` and `const name` offer varying outputs. Run the snippets below to see what I mean.

If it has anything to do with `name` being a `window` object property, then *re-declaring/defining* `name` with `const` should result in an error I would think. However, in the example(s) below, `const` allows for the re-declaration of `name` as an array, while `var` does not.

```js
var name = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
for (var i=0; i < name.length; i++){
    document.write(name[i] + '<br>');
}
```

```js
const name = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];
for (var i=0; i < name.length; i++){
    document.write(name[i] + '<br>');
}
```

So, why does `const` allow me to *hijack* the `window.name` property and reassign it as an array? But `var` does not allow for the reassignment (remains as default `string`)? Or am I simply looking at it the wrong way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `const`, like `let`, is [lexically scoped](http://www.2ality.com/2015/02/es6-scoping.html), and the top-level lexical scope is not the same as global scope. Here's an analogy:

```
function f(){
  var name = 1;
  {
    var name = 2; // does not create a new variable, because name already exists at the top level of the function
  }
  console.log(name); // 2
}

function g(){
  var name = 1;
  {
    const name = 2; // creates a new variable
  }
  console.log(name); // 1
}
```

`const` isn't *hijacking* `window.name`; it's just shadowing it. You can see this by observing in your second case that `window.name` remains unchanged. You can think of top-level code as if it's within the nested block in the functions above: `var` declarations get put in the global scope, but `let` and `const` declarations do not.

Comment: It should also be noted that `let` acts like `const`, for the same reason.

Comment: Gotcha. I knew that about `let`, but was unaware that `const` followed the same constraint. Learn something new every day.